# How do I use Boost Graph Library from Objective-C++?

Tags: xcode, macos, boost, objective-c++, boost-graph

Trying to figure out how to use BGL from within Objective-C++.  Something is amiss.  Steps to repro:

1. New Cocoa Application project.
2. Rename MyAppDelegate.m to MyAppDelegate.mm
3. Add `#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>` to MyAppDelegate.mm (works fine, assuming you have your header search paths set right.)
4. Add `#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>` to MyAppDelegate.mm

Something transitively included by `boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp` is colliding with some old Carbon headers that are being transitively imported by the Cocoa headers. Here is the output I see (the first error's worth anyway):

```
In file included from /Users/me/Documents/Projects/BoostTest/BoostTest/MyAppDelegate.mm:10:
In file included from /Users/me/Documents/Projects/BoostTest/boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp:33:
In file included from /Users/me/Documents/Projects/BoostTest/boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp:27:
In file included from /Users/me/Documents/Projects/BoostTest/boost/pending/property.hpp:13:
In file included from /Users/me/Documents/Projects/BoostTest/boost/type_traits.hpp:35:
In file included from /Users/me/Documents/Projects/BoostTest/boost/type_traits/has_operator.hpp:12:
In file included from /Users/me/Documents/Projects/BoostTest/boost/type_traits/has_bit_and.hpp:43:
/Users/me/Documents/Projects/BoostTest/boost/type_traits/detail/has_binary_operator.hpp:154:42: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
   static ::boost::type_traits::yes_type check(has_operator); // this version is preferred when operator exists
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
In file included from /Users/me/Documents/Projects/BoostTest/BoostTest/MyAppDelegate.mm:9:
In file included from /Users/me/Documents/Projects/BoostTest/BoostTest/MyAppDelegate.h:9:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Headers/Cocoa.h:12:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:76:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSURLError.h:12:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:23:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/AE.framework/Headers/AE.h:20:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/CarbonCore.h:115:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/Debugging.h:212:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/AssertMacros.h:1291:28: note: expanded from macro 'check'
        #define check(assertion)  __Check(assertion)
                                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/AssertMacros.h:280:5: note: expanded from macro '__Check'
                  do                                                                      \
                  ^
```

If I remove the `#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>` from the project's prefix header, and then `#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>` before including `<Cocoa/Cocoa.h>` in MyAppDelegate.mm things will compile, but this is sub-optimal/undesirable.

Is there something simple I can do (ideally in the prefix header so I don't have to do this everywhere) to make the Cocoa headers and the BGL headers co-exist peacefully?

Answer (score 1):

Should have googled for *epsilon* more time before asking. Just after posting this I found [this page](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6219) which explains that adding the following line prior to including the Cocoa headers will do the trick:

```
#define __ASSERT_MACROS_DEFINE_VERSIONS_WITHOUT_UNDERSCORES 0
```

I had tried doing that in my individual MyAppDelegate.mm file, and it didn't work, but that was because of the prefix header. Adding it to the project's prefix header prior to its inclusion of `Cocoa/Cocoa.h` did the trick.